# Кириллица в навигационном меню WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, utf-8, кириллица

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой кодировки в WordPress. Но! Кодировка работает не корректно только в редактировании навигационного меню. Вот что я вписываю до:
 [image: wordpress]

и что я имею после:

[image: wordpress проблема с кодировкой]

В конфиге стоит UTF-8, база тоже. Вычитал что такого рода проблемы только на Windows. Залил на хостинг, действительно все работает нормально. Может проблема в настройках PHP/MуSQL? Идеи? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: в конкретный момент, когда редактируете это поле, страница у вас в какой кодировке отображается?

Comment: В браузере UTF8 (автоматически)

Comment: Надо в БД посмотреть все переменные, связанные с charset... Их поправить, если кто не UTF-8. При коннекте также нужно `SET NAMES utf-8` прописать. Сейчас сохраняется в кодировке CP1252. Это даже не стандартная виндовая (после XP SP3). Где-то эта кодировка все же засела.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду в настройках БД? Просто интересно, что это случается только в меню. Например при создании постов, все сохраняется нормально.

Comment: Когда заливали на хостинг, там такой-же набор плагинов?

Comment: да, там  бесплатный хостинг, я просто залил туда все файлы